# How to remove parent directory without deleting sub folders?

Tags: shell, rm, mv

For Example,

I have 5 directories inside parent directory, I want to delete parent directory without deleting 5 subdirectories.

As of now am doing with below code,

```
 mv parentFolder/* parentFolder/.. && rm -rf parentFolder
```

Do we have any other simpler option than this?

Answer (score 1):

```
mv parentFolder/* parentFolder/..
```

Would move all the (non-hidden) files, not only those of type *directory*.

To move only the directories, with `zsh` (also shortening the code)

```
(){mv $1/{*(/),..} && rm -rf $1} parentFolder
```

Or to include hidden ones:

```
(){mv $1/{*(D/),..} && rm -rf $1} parentFolder
```

- `(){..$1..} arg`: anonymous function with an argument (to factorise the `parentFolder`)
- `{a,b}` csh-style brace expansion, also to factorize
- `(/)`: glob qualifier to select only directories. You could also do `*/` (which would also work in `bash`, but would also include symlinks to directories).
- `(D/)`: `D` for dot-files (hidden files whose name starts with `.`).